# why does tuna in olive oil and cooking cream often go wrong

Tags: cream, olive-oil, tuna

When mixing tuna (from a can and heated with a little olive oil) with cooking cream (panna), often the whole thing goes wrong, unfortunately:

Instead of having a nice homogenized creamy sauce, the cream flocks-out (becomes cottage cheese like) and the tuna swims in greasy oil.

Why does this happen? It never occurs, when I heat chopped tomatoes together with the tuna and add the cream.

Comment: did you heat the tuna first with olive oil?

Comment: @Cubic273.15 yes, as I wrote "tuna (from a can and heated with a little olive oil)"

Comment: what if you put cooking cream first, heat it up, and add olive oil + tuna later?

Comment: @Cubic273.15 never tried this way, it would mean another dirty pan though. Anyway, I suppose it must have to do with either the olive oil or the fish' oil make the cream separating. As I wrote in my Q: this never happens if I cook tomatoes together with the tuna. But I like that more "carbonara style" variant of the tuna sauce.